# How to install virtualbox in ubuntu by command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL on Windows 10 Home Version.

The Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS.

I did these:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Then run:

```
$ VBoxManage --version
```

The error was:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-3.4.0+.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.0.36_Ubuntur114008
```

Run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

The message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
virtualbox-dkms is already the newest version (5.0.36-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2).
virtualbox-dkms set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Then, how to install?

Comment: You can't. Use the Windows version directly.

Comment: @cylgalad Do you mean use the version which been installed on windows? Then how to use it?

Comment: Install `dkms` and the `linux-headers` package

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a latest version of VirtualBox, check the [official documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Add one of the following lines according to your distribution to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib
```

Alternatively, you can use add-apt-repository to add to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib"
```

Add secure key:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Install VirtualBox:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Comment: I have tried this way but the result was the same.